# How do I pass Page title to the menu (like breadcrumbs)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to develop a mobile view for an application.
I have menus on my footer component, I have header component, pages and subpages (component).

```
  import React from 'react' 
    import {Link} from Gatsby
    export default Nav =() => {
         const menu = [
    {
       url: '/',
       title: 'Home', 
     },
     {
      url: '/about'
      title: 'About'
     },
      {
      url: '/contact'
      title: 'Contact'
     },
      
    ]
    return (
           <ul>
{menu.map(item => {
     <li>
<Link to="{item.title}">{item.title}</Link>
</li>
})}
</ul>
)
    }
```

**For my header**
I have a place a component to display the content but I want to pass the clicked menu title on the header menu (another component entirely). I want to know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use state props of `<Link />`

Here is an example:

```
const PhotoFeedItem = ({ id }) => (
  <div>
    {/* (skip the feed item markup for brevity) */}
    <Link
      to={`/photos/${id}`}
      state={{ fromFeed: true }}
    >
      View Photo
    </Link>
  </div>
)

const Photo = ({ location, photoId }) => {
  if (location.state.fromFeed) {
    return <FromFeedPhoto id={photoId} />
  } else {
    return <Photo id={photoId} />
  }
}
```

Or you can do it using the navigate function.

Comment: I'm talking of the NAV, it does not have id.

Comment: Try this code `<Link to={item.url} state={{title: item.title}}>{item.title}</Link`.
Then you can get the title from `props.state.title`.